# Android chromium disk_cache error : Corrupt Index file

Tags: android

I am just trying to do a -

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

But I get blank page with the following error in the log-

> 07-05 17:20:30.623: E/chromium(1243):
>   external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:2022:
>   [0705/172030:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(2022)] Corrupt Index file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packet data was not enabled, which caused me the error.